# How to display result of query in controller

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4, controller

I am having difficulty in displaying result of query.

This is code I used to extract data from table. The table name is `adtresults`
I want to extract the data from column name `enter_input`

```
$value= "hospital one"
$user=DB::table('adtresults')->where('enter_input', $value);
 foreach($user as $users){echo $users->enter_input;}
```

The error is `Trying to get property of non-object`

Comment: remove `foreach` and do a `var_dump($user)` to see what the value is for `$user`

Comment: t(Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder)#194 (27) { ["connection":protected]=> object(Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection)#187 (17) { ["pdo":protected]=> object(PDO)#188 (0) { } ["readPdo":protected]=> NULL ["reconnector":protected]=> object(Closure)#193 (2) { ["this"]=> object(Illuminate\Database\DatabaseManager)#92 (4) { ["app":protected]=> object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application)#2 (16) { ["booted":protected]=> bool(true) ["bootingCallbacks":protected]=> array(0) { } ["bootedCallbacks":protected]=> array(2) { [0]=> object(Closure)#74 (2) { ["static"]=> array(2) { [ *RECURSION*

Comment: displays some thing like this

Comment: this is some part of the result it shows

Comment: that should be enough information for you to realize that you aren't getting a Collection object as expected. Take a look at @mdamia answer for the solution

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question whenever you want to provide more information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed 'get()' method at the end.

change this

```
$user=DB::table('adtresults')->where('enter_input', $value);
```

to

```
$user=DB::table('adtresults')->where('enter_input', $value) -> get();
```

Hope this help.